# i just want to remove via and extra stuff written in header of mail

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

[click herer to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPomu.png)

```
$email = validate_input($_POST['email']);
$headers = "From: donotreply@xyz.co.nz"."\r\n". "CC: coach@xyz.co.nz";  $body = "Hi, Thank you for subscribing . Please find the link below for FREE 1 week course on Basic’s of Freestyle.\n\nwww.xyz.com/freecourse.php";
$body = wordwrap($body,70);
$mail = mail($email, "| Basic’s of Freestyle", $body,$headers);
```

Comment: Please, read [mcve] and modify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved by just adding  -f after header 

`$mail = mail($email, "| Basic’s of Freestyle", $body,$headers,'-fcoach@xyz.co.nz');`